# MSQL Update Table 1 Using Table 2 UPDATE FROM SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I'm trying to update the country_id's of table1 so i can delete the columns `iso_2_code` and `Country` as this data is redundant in the db and is already stored in table2

Table1 - oc_ip_geo_table

```
=================================================================================================
|   ID  |    StartRange     |   EndRange        |   iso_2_code  |   Country     |   country_id  |
=================================================================================================
|  1    |    1.0.1.0        |   1.0.3.255       |       CN      |   China       |       0       |
|  2    |    1.0.4.0        |   1.0.7.255       |       AU      |   Australia   |       0       |
|  3    |    1.0.8.0        |   1.0.15.255      |       CN      |   China       |       0       |
|  4    |    1.0.16.0       |   1.0.31.255      |       JP      |   Japan       |       0       |
|  ...  |    ...            |   ...             |       ...     |   ...         |       ...     |
| 87035 |    223.255.255.0  |   223.255.255.255 |       AU      |   Australia   |       0       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table2 - oc_country

```
=================================================================================
|   country_id      |   name            |   iso_code_2  |   *   |   *   |   *   |
=================================================================================
|       1           |   Afghanistan     |       AF      |   *   |   *   |   *   |
|       2           |   Albania         |       AL      |   *   |   *   |   *   |
|       3           |   Algeria         |       DZ      |   *   |   *   |   *   |
|       ...         |   ...             |       ...     |   ... |   ... |   ... |
|       251         |   Canary Islands  |       IC      |   *   |   *   |   *   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After Searching to the google results i found that my Query should looklike this. but it seems not to work.

```
UPDATE oc_ip_geo_table
SET oc_ip_geo_table.country_id = oc_country.country_id
FROM oc_ip_geo_table
INNER JOIN oc_country
ON oc_ip_geo_table.iso_2_code = oc_country.iso_code_2
```

Can anyone help me with the correct Query

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems the query i was trying before the one i posted up here was almost correct however changing one bit solved it

```
UPDATE oc_ip_geo_table AS t1
SET t1.country_id = 
    ( SELECT t2.country_id 
      FROM oc_country AS t2 
      WHERE t2.iso_code_2 = t1.iso_2_code

    )
```

Changed into

```
UPDATE oc_ip_geo_table AS t1
SET t1.country_id = 
    ( SELECT t2.country_id 
      FROM oc_country AS t2 
      WHERE t1.iso_2_code = t2.iso_code_2

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not shure.. but i think you have to remove `oc_ip_geo_table` after SET

```
UPDATE oc_ip_geo_table
SET country_id = occ.country_id
FROM oc_ip_geo_table opi
INNER JOIN oc_country occ
ON opi.iso_2_code = occ.iso_code_2
```

Comment: Tnxs for your comment i also tried that but that dint work however this seems to work
UPDATE oc_ip_geo_table AS t1
SET t1.country_id = 
    ( SELECT t2.country_id 
      FROM oc_country AS t2 
      WHERE t1.iso_2_code = t2.iso_code_2

    )